# how to extract an attribute value of div using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a div whose id is "img-cont"

```
<div class="img-cont-box" id="img-cont" style='background-image: url("http://example.com/example.jpg");'>
```

I want to extract the url in background-image using beautiful soup.How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can you `find_all` or `find` for the first match.

```
import re 
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_str)
result = soup.find('div',attrs={'id':'img-cont','style':True})
if result is not None:
  url = re.findall('\("(http.*)"\)',result['style']) # return a list.
```

Comment: I have done that part.How to extract url from the result variable?

Comment: Thanks, It worked!!Could you please explain me this part  "url = re.findall('\("(http.*)"\)',result['style'])".

Comment: the `result['style']` return the string `'background-image: url("http://example.com/example.jpg");'` and the `re.findall()` is a regex search, to read more about regex check this link https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''\
<div class="img-cont-box" \
id="img-cont" \
style='background-image: url("http://example.com/example.jpg");'>\
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
div = soup.find('div', id='img-cont')
print(re.search(r'url\("(.+)"\)', div['style']).group(1))
```